# Background image inside a stack in Ruby Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

I've been trying to set a background image to the stack but I can't get it to work, am I doing something wrong? Here's my code

```
Shoes.app(:width => 550,
      :height => 450) do

#Main container so I don't have to deal with scroll
stack(:width  => 550,
      :height => 450,
      :scroll => false) do
    background(image("img/intro_bg.jpg"))
end
```

end

I'm trying to avoid the scroll bar to appear since the re-size property doesn't work at all :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `img/intro_bg.jpg` exists, please change

```
background(image("img/intro_bg.jpg"))
```

to

```
background('img/intro_bg.jpg')
```

Comment: It's an old and bad habit of using the double quotes but your answer did help me out. Thanks :)